# The relationship between structural budget balance and cyclically adjusted budget balance?

Tags: macroeconomics

What is the relationship between structural budget balance and the cyclically adjusted budget(*CAB*) balance?

I know that $PB=\textit{CAB}+AS$, where $PB$ is primary budget,  and $AS$ are the automatic stabilizers(tax revenues, unemployment benefits, etc. $AS$ term is counter-cyclical, i.e negative in recessions, positive in booms).

My question is, how do I relate, mathematically, the structural budget and the CAB?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I found out that Structural Budget is OECD nomenclature for Cyclically Adjusted Budget.

Here's a [link](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=2577).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7654)

Comment: @denesp Added a link. Not sure what else could be added.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Yesterday I misunderstood the question. This is a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cylical adjustment is simply a trendline based on past GDP. The structural budget balance is the balance with this trend removed. It is similar to seasonal adjustments, except over a longer period.